# Same code's exported apk in Android Studio is way bigger than Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have this very simple application with one simple Activity that on start downloads a file from a server. That's it. Nothing more. Yet when I export this application from Android Studio, the apk size is 1.1 MB, and when I export it from IntelliJ IDEA, it becomes as small as 40 KB. That's a HUGE difference.

What might be wrong here? Everything is in default mode, just the IDE differs here.

Comment: Yes. Both of them work just the same.

Comment: It's because intellij remove some useless resource ,like image .And you haven't set in android studio.

Comment: Follow this to fix the shrinking problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337057/shrinkresources-set-to-true-but-all-unused-resources-specifically-drawables-n/ ... I had the same issue a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Need to set the shrinkResource to true

And also set the shrinkMode to strict for maximum shrinking.

Follow this link
[shrinkResources set to true, but all unused resources (specifically drawables) not getting removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337057/shrinkresources-set-to-true-but-all-unused-resources-specifically-drawables-n/)