# remove android-support-v7-appcompat resources

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat, minify

For minifying my app I've done below steps:

---

In Gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I've added required proguard rules in `proguard-rules.pro`

Also I've added

```
    defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "en"
}
```

And I removed unused resources from my project:

***Refactor/Remove Unused Resources***

---

Now when I generate signed app and open my app (with WinRAR) I see that still there are some resources in `drawable` that I don't use in my app.

like `abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015`(checkbox icon) `abc_ic_star_black_48dp`(rating icon) etc.

I'm using `appcompat` , `design` , `cardview` and `recyclerview` library.

Can I remove them too? How?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337057/shrinkresources-set-to-true-but-all-unused-resources-specifically-drawables-n)