# shrink resources does not work for libraries modules

Tags: android, proguard, minify, android-module, shrinkresources

I have some library modules in my application and there are a lot of resources that are unused. But they did not remove in release build.

**minifyEnabled** has been set **true** in release buildType and also **shrinkResources** has set **true** in `app` module.

Note: Proguard worked correctly and remove all of the unused source codes.(including library module source codes).

P.S: I know that we can't use **shrinkResources** option in library modules and this shrinking is `app` module responsibility.

**UPDATE1 :** I read [this thread's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34337677/2389923). Although I didn't use `getIdentifier()`, it hasn't effect.

**UPDATE2:** According to below quote, I checked `R` class in output apk and I found references(`id`) to unused resources. Why are they there?

> Proguard works on the Java side. Unfortunately, it doesn’t work on the resources side. As a consequence, if an image my_image in res/drawable is not used, Proguard only strips it’s reference in the R class but keeps the associated image in place.
>   [source](https://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/)

Answer (score 1):

I checked `shrinkResources` option and it works somehow.
`shrinkResources` did not remove unused resources rather it clears file contents. For unused xml I saw an empty xml like this in the output apk:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x />
```

I don't know the reason behind clearing content instead of deleting the file. 
This approach is not optimal but is acceptable. An empty xml like the above one occupies 47 bytes.

Comment: What the hell is going on? :/ Most of our unused resources are `.png` files and according to your answer, some of them converted to 1x1 pixel black png. but I can find a lot of unchanged png files in apk.